# List view in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, listview

i have list view inside list view a button when i click button list view insert template show give me example in csharp...
and i have nested list view again same method call

4 eaxmple

listview1-> Add-button ->click ->insert template show

listview1 -> select -> click ->listview2 show -> Add-button-> click-> insert template show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how are you Mr.Waqa

I think it should be like this :

listview1 -> **SelectedItemTemplate**  -> click ->listview2 show -> Add-button-> click-> insert template show

first you have to add the SelectedItemTemplate and you should add a button to show this template when you click on it.

after that you you have to go to the code behind and you have to find that listview2

after you find that control you have to find the "new" button which will allow you to show the insert template in the second list "listview2" ,and do the same as in your old question .